# "data.replace is not a function" while formatting the data in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]I am displaying the results from Solr in a Datatable using jQuery. The data is something like this:

```
vim_name: "CEE"
vim_release: "6.6.1"
vnf_information:"[Ericsson<>FGC 101 127<>R1A]|[Ericsson<>vSAPC<>1.3]|[Ericsson_vSGSN-MME_v1.2399999]"
```

I tried to render it in the datatable in the below way

```
{
  "data": "vnf_information", 
  render: (data, type, row, meta) => data ? data.replace(/|/g, '<br>') : ''
}
```

However its giving me an error:

> data.replace is not a function

I would like to print the output in the below format. How can I achieve that?

```
VNF Information
Ericsson_ FGC 101 127_R1A
Ericsson_vSAPC_1.3
Ericsson_vSGSN-MME_v1.2399999
```

pls see below how the data is coming in the render.

[image]

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing what value `data` holds. Judging from the error I would assume it's `undefined`, `null`, or a integer/float

Comment: vnf_information:"[Ericsson<>FGC 101 127<>R1A]|[Ericsson<>vSAPC<>1.3]|[Ericsson_vSGSN-MME_v1.2399999]" this is the value it holds

Comment: I don't believe that is true, as if it was your code would work: https://jsfiddle.net/k02fvjzt/. `console.log(data)` inside `render` to see what the actual value is.

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture of the result i am getting in solr.Can you please check

Comment: That image is not what I meant. I can see that's the initial data you have. However the problem is that is not the data being received in the `render` handler. That is where you need to check the value.

Comment: I have updated the question ,can u pls check the last line.Its coming as an array

Comment: Thank you - that was the important missing piece. I've added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the second screenshot, it appears `data` is an array and the string you're expecting is the first value in that array. Therefore to fix the error you need to simply access the `data` array by index.

Also note that you will need to escape the pipe operator in the regular expression, as it has a special meaning. Try this:

```
{
  "data": "vnf_information", 
  render: (data, type, row, meta) => data ? data[0].replace(/\|/g, '<br>') : ''
}
```

Note the addition of `[0]`

Comment: sorry above dint work the below one worked.with an escape smbol

Comment: "data": "vnf_information", 
                
                 render: (data, type, row, meta) => data ? data[0].replace(/\|/g, '<br>') : ''

Comment: Also now how can i remove the square brackets and replace <> with _  as in my question

Comment: You can use `replace()` for those too, exactly as you already do.